# undefined в консоле JavaScript хотя вроде всё нормально

Tags: javascript, функции

Так, вот основной код:

```
const people = [
    {name: 'Elena', budget: '2222'},
    {name: 'Luisa', budget: '3000'},
    {name: 'David', budget: '3500'}
]
const person = people.find(function(person) {
    return person.budget === 3500
})

console.log(person)
```

Если что, скрипт пустой, ничего кроме предоставленного нету
То есть, никаких вроде ошибок, и путаниц, но на выходе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Попробовал вот так:

```
const person = people.find((person) => {
    return person.budget === 3500
})

console.log(person)
```

Но тоже без результатно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам лучше бы изменить массив с объектами. Цены на товары не должны быть строками, их лучше сделать числами

Что вы делаете:

1. Вы проходитесь циклом по массиву (метод find это цикл)
2. Ходите по объектам person, у которого есть два поля: 1-name, является строкой; 2-budget, является строкой
3. Проверяете что у объекта `person` поле `budget`(является строкой) строго сравниваете, что он будет равняться числу(другой тип данных)

в JavaScript если строго сравнить строку `'3500'` и число `3500` будет false (ты так сравниваешь в своём примере кода)

```js
const people = [{
    name: 'Elena',
    budget: '2222'
  },
  {
    name: 'Luisa',
    budget: '3000'
  },
  {
    name: 'David',
    budget: '3500'
  }
]
const person = people.find(function(person) {
  return person.budget === '3500'
})

document.write(`
  <h1>Вот чему равняется переменная person:</h1>
  <pre>${JSON.stringify(person)}<pre>
`);
```

Comment: Тоже не работает...

Comment: @dastermaf нажми тут на сайте выполнить код, тут всё работает

Comment: создал отдельный html с джавой, вроде всё заработало :)

Comment: @dastermaf с javascript'ом, java это другой язык программирования

Comment: не понял, но ладно, придётся как-то перенести html основной в новый.. какая-то видимо ошибка... лан, спасибо вам реально

Comment: @dastermaf можешь прочитать текст в ответе, я дописал пояснение

Answer (score 2):

У вас в `budget` - строковые значения. Ищите вы через **строгое сравнение** с конкретным **числом**. Внимание вопрос: что должно найтись?

Comment: Можете с кодом объяснить?) Мне надо перевести числа в let?

Comment: @dastermaf вы знаете разницу между строгим и не строгим сравнением? Или вообще что это такое в принципе?

Answer (score 0):

Ну вам уже вроде максимально подробно все объяснили. Скину просто два рабочих варианта, но это будут не совсем верные подходы, которые вряд ли стоит использовать на реальных проектах.

```js
const people = [
    {name: 'Elena', budget: '2222'},
    {name: 'Luisa', budget: '3000'},
    {name: 'David', budget: '3500'}
];
const person = people.find(person => parseInt(person.budget) === 3500);

console.log(person)
```

```js
const people = [
        {name: 'Elena', budget: '2222'},
        {name: 'Luisa', budget: '3000'},
        {name: 'David', budget: '3500'}
    ];
    const person = people.find(person => person.budget == 3500);

    console.log(person)
```

PS: я заменил Вашу функцию внутри find() на стрелочную лишь для более короткой записи. На работу это никак не влияет и Вы можете передавать функцию, с телом и return внутри, но зачем это делать в данном случае?)

Answer (score -1):

Вот так будет работать

```
const person = people.find((person) => {
    return Number(person.budget) === 3500
})

console.log(person)
```